# Android-keep connected to a website to receive database notifications

Tags: java, android, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing an android app. I need to get notified if the value in the database changes. For that I am using an asp.net website which uses SqlDefendency and OnChange method to get notifications from SQL server database.
If the value changes, the website returns the new value using Response.write() method. So, can I keep connected to my website from android in order to receive this response?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the workflow to this:

- With some interval send request to your web server (with last known value if needed) from your mobile app
- Webserver will query database and based on new value from database and last known value will produce desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an api for your web server that checks database on demand and returns values. Then in your app you should write a thread that calls the api and checks changes at a certain fix time.

You can pass information between server and application with protocols like json or soap.

This way you are always connected to your webserver and you can get notifications.